# Nonzero probability for all time: is it certain it will happen?

Tags: probability

Is there any possible time varying probability function for an event occurring that is nonzero at all times but the probability of the event it describes occurring over eternity be less than 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just like infinite sums of strictly positive quantities can converge to a finite value, so [infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) can converge to finite values. All it requires is that $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \log(1-P_i)$$
converges. (which is the logarithm of the probability that "something" never happens)

Comment: That shows convergence, but, for instance, something like (1-p)^n converges to 0. But that shows that the event does happen. So is proving convergence enough?

Comment: The logarithm is important. If $p$ were constant and not $0$, $\sum \log(1-p)$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Doesn't the I finite product (1-p)^n clearly go to 0?

Comment: Oh, if the product is zero it is said to diverge...just read the Wikipedia article. Thanks, I'll think about this some more.

Comment: It does, but that wasn't your question: you asked if it was possible for it to converge to a nonzero value.